# Building a project with files pending on a parameter

Tags: c++, c, include, seam

I am trying to find a way to build a C/C++ project to only include certain files depending on an input i.e, if its parameter a include files 1-5. parameter b include files 6-10, etc etc.  Basically a script or something to build a project based off of an input for visual studio.  Only ideas I have came up with is using preprocessor commands which dont seem to work, using namespace command but I am unsure how to even use it, or writing a script in some fashion but I dont know how I would go about that either.

The reason is because I cannot edit some of the internal files of the application and they share some of the same function names.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How exactly would you provide the input ?

Answer (score 4):

```
#ifdef MY_FLAG
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
#include "header3.h"
#include "header4.h"
#include "header5.h"
#endif

#ifdef MY_OTHERFLAG
#include "header6.h"
#include "header7.h"
#include "header8.h"
#include "header9.h"
#include "header10.h"
#endif
```

Believe me, this works :) Just make sure you define them properly.

[alt text http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/1157/myflag.gif](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/1157/myflag.gif)

Answer (score 2):

You might also be able to play some games to wrap the files with the same function names, i.e:

In wrapper.c:

```
   #define funca file1_funca
   #include "file1.c"
   #undef funca
```

It's a little dirty, but it could work.